# Algothm Analysis bigO and normal notation

Tags: c++, algorithm, analysis

```
int I(int i, int j, int n) 
{ 
   return n * i + j;                                    >1
}
int DotProduct( int A[], int B[], int i, int j, int n )
{
   int t=0;                                             >1
   for(int k=0; k<n; k++ )                              > n+1              
      t += A[ I(i,k,n) ] * B[ I(k,j,n) ];               > n
   return t;                                            > n 
}
void MMultiply( int A[], int B[], int C[], int n ) 
{
   for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )                          > n+1
      for( int j=0; j<n; j++ )                       > (n)n+1
         C[ I(i,j,n) ] = DotProduct(A, B, i, j, n );  > see function above (n)(n)(3n+2)?
}
```

im not sure if i should post on the old post or a new one so ill post on a new one just because this is urgent ( studying for a midterm)

anyways i know the big O is n^3

(3n+2)(n)(n)+ (n+1)(n)+ (n+1)  < did i do this right?

arg i hate when teacher teaches something that is not on the book!

Comment: `MMultiply()` is O(n^3), correct.

Comment: i know lol there is an answer but no steps so im trying on my steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start from the beginning: you first need to calculate the time it takes tu run an average case MMultiply:

The first thing you can see in MMultiply is a loop from 0 to n - 1, that gives you:

T(MMultiply) = n*(T(what_is_inside_the_first_loop))

Now you need T(what_is_inside_the_first_loop). As you only have another loop inside the first loop,  T(what_is_inside_the_first_loop) =  n*T(what_is_inside_the_second_loop)

Inside the second loop is only a single call to "DotProduct" so, disregarding the "=" assignment, T(what_is_inside_the_second_loop) = T(DotProduct).

To calculate T(DotProduct), you take the function line-by-line:

- 1 for the initial assignement
- n for the loop
- 3 for each iteration of the loop (1 for the "+=" operation and 1 for each call to I - which only does one operation)

so T(DotProduct) = 1 + n*3

replacing T(DotProduct) in the initial ecuation gives you:

T(MMultiply) = n * n * (1 + n*3) = 3*n^3 + n^2

so

T(MMultiply) = 3*n^3 + n^2

the big O notation basically just assigns this time to a specific class (it's an approximation). The class which approximates "3*n^3 + n^2" best is n^3 (since n^3 is the most significant member). So T(MMultiply) = O(n^3).

Your calculations were almost right, but you had a "+ 1" surplus on the first two lines of MMultiply and, if you commented on each line the time it takes to process that line, "t += A[ I(i,k,n) ] * B[ I(k,j,n) ]; " does not take n, it only takes 2. Same goes for "return t", it takes only 1.

Answer (score 0):

simple approach:

- count number of nested loops:  `N^3`
- count number of operations: 2 (+,*)
- totally is `2N^3`

Comment: Since he's given it as a single equation, `(3n+2)(n)(n)+ (n+1)(n)+ (n+1) `, I believe looking for the highest degree of the equation is the way to calculate the O notation. As shown in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example